# How to convert a number into a string and use it as an array key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, key

I'm trying to convert a number to a string to use as a key. But the problem is, when I the newly converted string, it still acts like a number. Is there a right way of doing this?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var arr = [];

var num = 3;

var key = String(''+num); //Convert number into string

//var key = ''  +num;         //Tried this
//var key = num.toString(); //Tried this also

array[key] = true;

console.log(arr); //Returns [, , true]
console.log(arr.length); //Returns 3
```

Basically, I want it to return just:

```
console.log(arr); //Return [true]
console.log(arr.length); //Return 1
```

Comment: and what do you want? please add the result as well.

Comment: JavaScript turns any expression you use with the `[ ]` operator into a string. You don't have to do anything at all. `arr[3]` is the same as `arr["3"]`.

Comment: Hello, sorry, added my desired result to question

Comment: how do you map `3` to index `0`?

Comment: @tery.blargh OK well the answer is you cannot do that. You could use a plain object instead of an array however.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but arrays don't have "keys", probably you want to use and Object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is an **Object** (`{}`) not an **Array** (`[]`). Use this instead:

```
var obj = {};
var key = 3;
obj[key] = true; // no need to convert the key to string
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var obj = {};
var key = 3;
obj[key] = true;

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: so you are looking for an object, instead of an array. plain object have no (built in) length property.

Comment: They do after `Object.keys()` :)